# Looking for a good introductory-level review of pseudopotential methods

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, computational-physics

I'm looking for a good introductory-level review of [pseudopotential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudopotential) methods. In particular, I'd like to understand how the self-consistent pseudopotential methods work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to read a review "Pseudopotential methods in condensed matter applications" by W.E. Pickett in Computer Physics Reports **9** 115-198 (1989). One of the best "introductions" that I found. It is supposed to be read by non-specialists, so it is rather short and not too technical.